# Finding indexes on a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 that were created within last 15 days

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

I created some new indexes within the last 15 days on a couple of tables in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Knowing the table name, is it possible to determine which indexes were created in last 15 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a big fan of backward compatibility views like `sysindexes` because you won't be able to rely on them forever, and because the join proposed in the other answer filters on create date of the *table*, not the *index*. For normal indexes, SQL Server simply does not log the date/time of when the index was created (though you can get this for constraints).

You *can* find this information (as well as who created the index, which you can't get from the metadata even for constraints) in the default trace, if 15 days haven't rolled out yet:

```
USE your_database;
GO

DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
  HostName, LoginName, ApplicationName, StartTime, [Index] = ObjectName, IndexId
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass = 46
AND EventSubClass = 1
AND DatabaseName = DB_NAME()
AND ObjectID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.your_table_name')
AND IndexID IS NOT NULL
AND StartTime >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY EndTime DESC;
```

Going forward, you could use a DDL trigger to log this information proactively, so you don't have to scramble and rely on the age of the default trace to audit these activities...

Comment: Aaron - I tried your query but it says: You do not have permission to run 'SYS.TRACES'. So I will need another approach. Thanks, Sunil

Comment: @Sunil well maybe that is something you need to fix. After all, if you're not allowed to query sys.traces, you are probably blocked from other metadata access as well.

Comment: Aaron - Is there some other query I could possibly use?

Comment: @Sunil not that I know of - as I said, SQL Server does not store this information for regular indexes. Convince the people above you that you need to find this information, then they can grant you access (even if only temporarily) or they can run the query for you. Surely someone who cares if you get the answer to this or not has the power to do one of those things.

Comment: Aaron - Actually the query from regisIs DOES return index names , and not table names. So it seems to be working.

Comment: @Sunil yes, it returns index names. Who is disputing that? Have you read anything I've said? It returns the wrong DATES. If your table is more than 15 days old, guess what? None of its indexes will be in the result, even if you created them 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Aaron- Ok., get I now.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select crdate, i.name, object_name(o.id)
from sysindexes i
join sysobjects o ON o.id = i.id
where crdate >= getdate()-15
```

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005** and newer, you should use `sys.indexes` from the `sys` catalog schema (and not the old, deprecated `sysindexes` views anymore)

Comment: That `crdate` is the creation date of the "base" object (ex. table).

Comment: @marc_s this is true, except `sys.indexes` no longer has a corresponding row in `sys.objects` for regular indexes, so you can't determine `create_date` this way. For a standard index that is not a constraint, the best you'll get from sys.objects (or sysobjects) is the create date of the table, not the index, anyway.

Comment: if Sunil needs it to meet a momentarily demand, it matters little whether the sysindexes is old and deprecated.

Comment: But surely it matters that this *doesn't give the right answer anyway*.

Comment: @Sunil Seriously, please look closer, this gives the *tables* that were created in the last 15 days, not the *indexes*.

Comment: This did return the results to me. But IS THIS NOT PROVIDING CORRECT DATA?

Comment: *groan* NO, it is not. It is returning TABLES that were created in the last 15 days.

Comment: WOW. How could I change this query to return indexes then?